# how do I change a TextArea component's font size in Flash using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textarea, components, textformat

I want to change the font size of Flash's TextArea component which is currently on the stage using AS3.

I tried linking a TextFormat object to the TextAera by its instance name, but I get this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 44  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method setTextFormat through a reference with static type fl.controls:TextArea.
```

Here is the AS3 code:

```
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
myTextFormat.size = 10;
myTextFormat.color = 0xffffff;

my_textArea.setTextFormat(myTextFormat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
myTextArea.setStyle("textFormat", myTextAreaFormat);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and it worked. However I would also like to know which class setStyle is associated with. I can find it within the TextArea or TextField documentation. Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation 'setStyle' is inherited by the UIComponent class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered is that the textFormat needs to be set ***prior*** to adding the text. When you do that, the setTextFormat command works fine. However, if you define the associated textFormat *after* its associated textField has been defined, it breaks and the font size isn't set.

1. define a wrapper (in mine, I used a sprite) for the textField
2. define textFormat for your textBox (in mine I defined "textBoxFormat")
3. define your text field (in mine, I used "textBox")
4. add textBox to it's wrapper
5. Finally, set the textFormat ==> textBox.setTextFormat(textBoxFormat);

add the wrapper from step 1 to the stage (or other element).

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure the first step is required, but I found it beneficial to wrap the textField, just to be safe. 34 years of programming out the door with my introduction to Adobe's weird "standards". Wish there was a practical alternative, but there doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

Although One answer is accepted, That doesn't work for me and I found this solution:

> import mx.controls.TextArea;
>
> _global.styles.TextArea.setStyle("fontFamily", "Arial");
>
> _global.styles.TextArea.setStyle("fontSize", 30);

PS: If you need in AS2 .